# Как починить списки (select) внутри блока (div) с contenteditable в хроме?

Tags: html, css, css3, google-chrome, webkit

Есть блок с `contenteditable`, внутри располагается текст с выпадающими списками в которых элементы списка с длинными названиями.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    text text text text text <select><option>bigbigbigbigbigbigbig</option></select> text text text text text text text 
</div>
```

Для списка я задаю максимальную ширину

```
select {
    max-width: 40px;
}
```

и получаю неадекватную высоту блока в хроме:
[image]

хотя в FF работает отлично:
[image]

Как побороть эту проблему?
[Пример в jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pipanchik/d5nbwn8z/3/)

```css
select {
  max-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  text text text text text
  <select>
    <option>bigbigbigbigbigbigbig</option>
  </select> text text text text text text text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mozilla вообще не переключает пункты option.
А в хроме можно попробовать это вылечить через:

```
div {
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

У Mac свои переключатели, поэтому они смотрятся лучше (красивее). тут же с max-width нужно будет подстроить стили.

Comment: также решается добавлением к списку vertical-align:top